# Differences of DirectX11 D3D11_MAP

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have a vertex buffer that some parts of it need to be updated *only once* every frame, so I created it as `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` with `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE`.

Since there are a lot of vertices (around 150k), I don't want to iterate over the entire buffer, only on the parts that were tagged to update.

To do so, I tag each "region" with a `DirtyVertexBuffer` flag and then skip untagged regions. To update the buffer I use `D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE`. The code is:

```
VertexType *vertices;
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
Vertex *vertex;
HRESULT result;

result = context->Map(m_vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE, 0, &mappedResource);
if (FAILED(result))
    return;

vertices = (DirectX::VertexPositionNormalTexture*)mappedResource.pData;

for (auto &material : materials) {
    if ((material.dirty & Material::Dirty::VertexBuffer) == 0) continue;

    material.dirty &= ~Material::Dirty::VertexBuffer;

    // Update vertex data
}

// release the access to the buffer
context->Unmap(m_vertexBuffer, 0);
```

My question is: Why is `D3D_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE` necessary here, instead of `D3D_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD`?

If I use the latter, the vertex buffer seems to be "zeroed" (only regions that changed are rendered). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> **D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD**
>
> Resource is mapped for writing; the previous contents of the resource will be undefined.
>
> **D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE**
>
> Resource is mapped for writing; the existing contents of the resource cannot be overwritten (see Remarks).

but since I mapped the resource, shouldn't the entire buffer be copied from VRAM to system RAM and then, when I unmap it, go back to the VRAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thinking, I think I found the answer, can someone confirm this?

When using `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` and `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE`, the CPU will have access only for writing (ok, that is very clear). Then, on every call to `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map`, a temporary buffer (something created with a [`_aligned_malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx)), which state is undefined.

Then, when using `D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD`, the previous vertex buffer is discarded, meaning that only the parts that changed are kept, since they are present in that temporary buffer.

In other hand, while using `D3D11_MAP_WRITE_NO_OVERWRITE`, the previous vertex buffer is kept and only the parts that changed are written.

Comment: That is more or less correct.  The buffer isn't really "temporary" but rather just a new buffer that future commands will use so the hardware doesn't need to wait until the original one is done being used.  When using `NO_OVERWRITE` the developer is promising that there is no hazard and the hardware doesn't need to wait, so no extra buffer is necessary.

Comment: But doesn't `Map` "return" a RAM buffer? In that case, I called "temporary" due to hypothesis that, if the first statement is true, then `Unmap` frees the RAM buffer when it is copied to VRAM.

Comment: Not exactly - on some systems it goes straight through to video memory.  But yes, on discrete GPUs, a separate buffer is created.  But when you use `DISCARD`, the reason you lose the old data is because *video* memory is uninitialized, not because the mapped memory is uninitialized.  Mapped writes are [write-combined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_combining) so the uninitialized data doesn't get transferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the enlightenment, now I have understood how these buffers work :)

Comment: Or you can use the alternative ID3D11DeviceContext1::UpdateSubresource1 function from DX11.1+ (which supports partial updates basically)

Comment: Why UpdateSubresource1 from DX11.1 and not UpdateSubresource from DX11? And also, since it is a dynamic buffer, it can't be `UpdateSubresource`'ed.